# Using LaTeX Beamer to create a presentation, how do I use an image as a background to cover the entire slide?

Tags: beamer

Here is a MWE that depicts my problem in trying to use a custom image as a background template for my beamer presentation.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,aspectratio=1610,handout]{beamer} 
\usetheme[block=fill,progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \tikz\node[opacity=0.2] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{./Figures/Image.png}};}

% Presentation attributes
\title{Title}
\subtitle{\small Subtitle}
\author[xxx]{Author} % Author
\institute{\small Institute}
\date{\tiny\today}

\begin{document}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, the image is not covering the entire slide (i.e. the left and top regions of the slide).  I also tried using different sized images to see if that could overcome the issue but they all resulted in missing the entire frame.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, tikz adds a small margin to each node. You can disable this by setting `inner sep=0pt`:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,aspectratio=1610,handout]{beamer} 
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \tikz\node[opacity=0.2,inner sep=0pt] {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image}};}
    
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\tiny}

% Presentation attributes
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author[xxx]{Author}% Author
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame Title}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Unrelated: be aware that if you specify both the height and the width of an image, it will be distorted in almost all cases. Either remove one of them or add `keepaspectratio`

Comment: I just found another blog regarding that `inner sep=0` just needed to be added!